# Standardize or subtract constant to data for regression

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I am attempting to create a prediction model using multiple linear regression.

One of the predictor variables I want to use is a percentage, so it ranges from 0 - 100.  I hypothesize that when it’s <50% there will be a negative effect on the target variable and when >50% a positive effect.

The mean of the predictor variable isn’t exactly 50 in my data set so I am unsure if I centre or Standardize this variable, or just subtract 50 from it to create the split I am looking for.

I am very new to statistics and self teaching myself at the moment, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can make the predictor a binary / categorical if it is so specific. 1 if >50and 0 if <= 50..

Comment: I'd like it to be remain continuous, I am just wondering if subtracting 50 directly will lead me down a wrong path vs standardizing or centering.

Comment: yeah you can center it at 50. standardizing doesn't matter, because it just scales your coefficients  by the standard deviation

Comment: However, even if you get a coefficient from this regression, i don't know how you jump from that to your conclusion. imagine a scenario when < 50 have a positive effect and > 50 has a even more positive effect. the coefficient will be say +1 , + 2... etc

Comment: how does this help you? Sorry you need to define the question and the problem honestly.

Comment: Digging through the data manually I can see that >50% has a positive effect and <50% a negative, with a more positive effect the closer it gets to 100% and vice versa.    This also makes sense given what the data set is that this would be the case.  I am very new to this and have no formal training, just self teaching as I go along, so I have no idea if I can just subtract constants like the way I want to or if that will screw something up.